# SQL Group strings with difference

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have this sql query:

```
select u.name, c.name
from user u
JOIN customer c on u.id = c.id
group by (u.name, c.join_date)
```

Which works fine, but some of the names in User table are written differently but with 1 or 2 chars of difference. How can I expand this query so for example strings like, Mary-Kate and Mary Kate and Marry Kate are grouped together?

Comment: You are looking for something called Fuzzy Matching.   I would recommend you consider metaphone.   The following article should be helpful.   
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fuzzy-string-matching-with-postgresql/

Comment: I know something like this exists, but I don't know how to add it to the group by.

Comment: if there are many names like that, you can not do that without matching. But if only Mary Kate, you can use "case when".

Comment: @M8765 . .  Your query doesn't make sense.  The `select` and `group by` columns do not match.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow your code, because the `select` conditions and the `group by` conditions do not match.  Your question is:

> How can I expand this query so for example strings like, Mary-Kate and Mary Kate and Marry Kate are grouped together?

Let me assume the query matches the question . . . say:

```
select u.name, count(*)
from user u
group by u.name;
```

Then based on your examples, you can aggregate only on the characters in the name.  That suggests `regexp_replace()` to replace noncharacters:

```
select min(u.name), count(*)
from user u
group by regexp_replace(u.name, '[^[:alpha:]]', '', 'g');
```

If you have an actual question about `join`ing, then ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  Try to avoid syntactically incorrect queries.